# Knp Snappy Bundle - wkhtmltopdf

Tags: symfony, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I will generate pdf from html-page and I want to display some part text on a new page. any idea? thanks

Comment: There are two relevant CSS properties `page-break-before` and `page-break-inside` that you should use ... read more about them [here](http://community.sitepoint.com/t/creating-page-breaks-in-wkhtmltopdf/38929) or [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering your own question.

Suppose two elements on the page, the first element should appear on the first page and second are respectively in the second page. (pdf file)

To do this you need to take the height of the first element and deduct the from height of the PDF file page. In this way a value is added as an bottom-padding of the first element. it working :)